# Problems with Building LuaBind [C++]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, lua, building, luabind

I'm currently trying to build LuaBind on Windows. I have already built Boost 1.58 and Lua 5.3, and I have set the environment variables LUA_PATH and BOOST_ROOT on my system.

However, when I open a VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt and navigate to the LuaBind directory on my computer, and type bjam and hit enter, I only get an error saying that bjam is not recognized as a command.

Could anybody try to clarify how to build LuaBind for me (on Windows, using VS2012)?

Comment: bjam is part of boost, do you have an entry pointing to the directory where bjam is located in your `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: I don't think so. How can I check/fix that?

Comment: You can check that in your systems settings for environment variables.

Comment: There are no environment variable named PATH. There are however, one named Path, which points to an NVidia directory in Program Files x86, but I guess that's unrelated to this.

Comment: That's the right one. Add the directory where bjam is found to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

"That's the right one. Add the directory where bjam is found to the variable."
-  πάντα ῥεῖ